# Would forcing a neuron's ion pumps to open stun someone?

Tags: science-based, weapons, science-fiction, brain

So let's say you can force a neuron, or group of neurons, to open their ion pumps and release an electric signal.  If a neuron suddenly fired off a signal, would this cause a small disruption in the nervous system and stun the victim, or would it cause something like a seizure?

Comment: I mean, which group of neurons? You could get anywhere from no effect to a heart attack to a seizure to curing the victim's depression, etc., heh. Most likely though, if you get enough of them going in the brain, you'd cause a seizure. You might want to try targeting e.g. the lower spinal cord instead, go for the legs, avoid stopping their heart. Btw check out http://www.m.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/types-of-seizures-their-symptoms.

Comment: I see the biological and/or storytelling aspects of this question, but what's the worldbuilding application?

Comment: For stun, you have to block connection between motor neurons and muscle tissue, it can be done chemically and is done chemically. But I guess you need at least some sort of ranged weapon or affecting huge areas and working immoderately or that all - you mught clarify that moment in your question. Or you might just take look at police stun gun effects - it already is kinda what you asking for.
@Frostfyre as usual, semi scientific explanation of plot device - strange question, stun gun is widely used in different stories.

Comment: The concept was central to a stun spell I was wanting to use, so I thought I'd check the idea's plausibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a medical student:
A single neuron in the brain will go almost completely unnoticed, if you could fire off several neurons in a coordinated fashion you could cause everything from a light twitch of a muscle to weird sensory experiences to a full grown seizure.

A full epileptic seizure is in fact just a chain reaction starting with a small area of the brain firing its neurons uncontrollably then spreading to the rest of the brain resulting in a state referred to as status epilepticus. It would be a very effective method of rendering someone temporarily harmless.

There are also other kinds of seizures which could result from this ability and I would suggest you look into the different kinds of epileptic attacks there is and choose whichever you see fits best for the purpose of your story. :)

Answer (score 3):

So from what I can tell, a single neuron, or even a lot of them misfiring would not cause what you want, unless it happened in just the right place.

[Neurons actually misfire somewhat regularly](https://www.quora.com/Do-neurons-ever-misfire-or-fail-to-fire-If-so-how-often), and while they can send mixed messages to your body, they don't usually cause you to be stunned or worse.

There is evidence that frequent heavy misfiring is a [contributing factor for OCD](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/287291.php), as well as autism, Parkinson's, epilepsy, and other mental diseases, depending on where and how they are happening.

If you were to target a specific site, such as the cerebellum to effect motor control, or the mesial (middle) part of the temporal lobe, which could cause an epileptic seizure, and get a large enough group of them to go off, then it might happen like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially if you want to immobilize an attacker through neuron attacks you're basically talking about a [stun gun](http://www.tbotech.com/stun-gun.htm) or something with similar effects.

If you manage to get a large enough collection of neurons firing in the brain you could get anywhere from no effect to a heart attack to a seizure to curing the victim's depression or making them make a funny face (heh), etc... You'll be taking a gamble. Most likely though, if you get enough of them going in the brain, you'd cause a seizure. There *are* types of seizures that lead to just momentary unconsciousness, see [absence seizures](http://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/neurology_neurosurgery/centers_clinics/epilepsy/seizures/types/), if you could somehow magically control that.

You might want to try targeting e.g. the lower spinal cord instead, go for the legs. Or target muscles, like the aforementioned stun gun.